# Count how many documents are in a collection per value for a specific field - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of Items with multiple documents stored in MongoDB. The structure is as follows:

```
{ id: 1, colour: red },
{ id: 2, colour: blue},
{ id: 3, colour: red },
{ id: 4, colour: green},
{ id: 5, colour: green}
```

I would like to count how many items are in the DB by colour. The result should be like this:

```
colour blue: 1
colour red: 2
colour green: 2
```

I would like to avoid the following two approaches since the records could be a really large number and as I can imagine, these would be inefficient and costly.

```
const items = await Item.find({ colour: {$in: ['red', 'blue', 'green']} });
items.forEach(item => {
  // do the counting here
});
```

NEITHER

```
const blue = await Item.find({ colour: blue }).count();
const red = await Item.find({ colour: red }).count();
const green = await Item.find({ colour: green }).count();
```

The closest I found to my problem is [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/filter-array-elements-in-mongodb-1586).

What is the best way to obtain these numbers?

**Thanks for the help!!**

Comment: check out this question, I think it's similar to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013318/mongo-count-occurrences-of-each-value-for-a-set-of-documents

Comment: @shadi1999 thank you very much! I think this is my answer! 

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently quite easy using [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/), doing like the following:

```
const result = await Item.aggregate().group({ _id: '$colour', count: { $sum: 1 }});
```

Or equivalent:

```
const result = await Item.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: '$colour', count: { $sum: 1 }} }]);
```

The above would result:

```
[
  { "_id": "blue", "count": 1 },
  { "_id": "red", "count": 2 },
  { "_id": "green", "count": 2 }
]
```

Basically what the above code does, is to create an object with the properties `_id` and `count`. In the `group` operator, we pass the value of the `_id` which is the property to query and match the desired documents. The result is an array of these objects.